Create private endpoint for Azure App Service Environment_v3 using Terraform
I need to create a new private endpoint for an Azure App Service Environment_v3 using Terraform but I am unable to come up with the code since the sub-resource type for App Service Environment is not available.
Could someone kindly assist me with the Terraform code for the same.

According to this documentation, the sub-resource type should be hosting environment.
This documentation may also assist you on your endeavor.

This sub-resource type is for App service plan. I am looking for the sub-resource for app service environment

If you look at the resource ID or the resource JSON of an ASE_v3, the resource type is Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments. That resource type aligns with hosting environment sub-resource type value on the documentation I linked previously.
